# Trying to figure out a game of Hangman

Tags: python

I am an extreme beginner and am currently trying to create a game of hangman with Python 3.

Seemingly, the only issue that I am having trouble with is when the user inputs a character, I am not quite sure how to replace the "_"s with the correct letter that the user inputs.

```
import random


def hangman():
    # setting up the word and spacing
    possible_words = ["SOFTWARE", "COMPUTER", "RESEARCH", "BLIZZARD"]
    chosen_word = random.choice(possible_words)
    unknown_word = chosen_word
    # del
    print(chosen_word)
    # del
    for char in unknown_word:
        unknown_word = unknown_word.replace(char, "_ ")
    print(unknown_word)
    y = list(unknown_word)
    print()

    # Playing the game
    mistakes = 0
    incorrect_guesses = []
    while mistakes < 5:
        guess = input("Enter a guess:\n")
        length = len(guess)
        # PROBLEMS
        if guess.upper() in chosen_word and length == 1:
            print(unknown_word)
            print()
        # PROBLEMS
        elif length != 1:  # For if more than 2 characters are entered.
            print("Please enter a single character.")
            print()
            continue
        else:  # If the guess isn't in the string
            print("Incorrect guess!")
            mistakes += 1
            print("You have {0} attempts left".format(5 - mistakes))
            incorrect_guesses.append(guess)
            print("You have used {0} so far.".format(incorrect_guesses))
            print()
    print("GAME OVER")


hangman()
```

So, the issue that I need to figure out is what happens if the user enters the correct character.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can create `unknown_word` more simply with `unknown_word = "_ " * len(chosen_word)`

Comment: Loop through the characters in `chosen_word`. If the current character matches the guess, replace the corresponding `_` in `unknown_word` with the character. But remember that the indexes in `unknown_word` are twice the indexes in `chosen_word`, because of the space after each `_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest using a `set()` instead of a `list` for `incorrect_guesses` (you will need to use `.add` instead of `.append`). That way you will avoid having repeated values if the user repeats the same character.

You can also have a `correct_guesses` variable to keep track of the successful attempts and use them to avoid replace them with `_` in `unknown_word`.

Here's how the affected piece of code would like after that change:

```
    incorrect_guesses = set()
    correct_guesses = set()
    while mistakes < 5:
        guess = input("Enter a guess:\n")
        length = len(guess)
        char = guess.upper()
        if char in chosen_word and length == 1:
            correct_guesses.add(char)
            unknown_word = chosen_word
            for char in (c for c in unknown_word if c not in correct_guesses):
                unknown_word = unknown_word.replace(char, "_ ")
            print(unknown_word)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jacalvo! However, could you perhaps explain what these two lines of code do: 
    'for char in (c for c in unknown_word if c not in correct_guesses):
                    unknown_word = unknown_word.replace(char, "_ ")'. I tried to figure it a;; out on my own but am having trouble deciphering it.

Comment: `(c for c in unknown_word if c not in correct_guesses)` gives the list of the chars from `unknown_word` not present in correct_guesses, that is, the one that has not been guessed yet, and then we loop again on that result with the char variable to replace them with `"_ " ` in `unknown_word`. You can find more info about "generator expressions" on the many Python tutorials that are available online.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will replace the `_`'s with the original character:

```
unknown_word = ' '.join([guess.upper() if chosen_word[i] == \
                guess.upper() else c for i, c in enumerate(
                 unknown_word.replace(' ', ''))]
                ) + ' '
```

Comment: This will overwrite all the characters that were guessed correctly on previous turns with `_`.

Comment: The problem is fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like...

```
unknown_word = chosen_word #define the word
current_guess = '_'*len(unknown_word) #get the blanks (if you keep the spaces the loc parameter below will be multiplied by 2)
guessed_letter = input("Enter a guess:\n") #get the guessed letter

if guessed_letter in unknown_word:
    loc=unknown_word.index(guessed_letter)
    current_guess=current_guess[:loc]+guessed_letter+current_guess[loc+1:]
```

this will replace the blank with the letter in it's respective position, if it's in the unknown_word

**as another mentioned..the index position (loc) will be multiplied by two if you keep the spaces**

EDIT - above only works with one occurrence of each letter...this will work for words with multiple occurrences of the same letter:

```
guessed_letter = input("Enter a guess:\n")
for loc in range(len(unknown_word)):
    if unknown_word[loc] == guessed_letter:
        current_guess = current_guess[:loc]+guessed_letter+current_guess[loc+1:]
```

Comment: This won't work if the same character appears multiple times in the word.

Comment: Ugh, in my answer I forgot that you can't assign to string indexes! But you forgot to multiply `loc` by `2`

Comment: :D .. I have the text in there regarding the multiplication but added a comment to be a clear